# How to get geographic data of any particular region of map in Geometry datatype format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, latitude-longitude, atlas, geometry-data-type

I am completely new to Geometry datatype format of a Microsoft SQL Server database. DataType is Geometry. If not wrong, geographic data contains latitude and longitude of each point of that map, correct me If I am wrong. Now I have to add data of particular region from map in SQL table in Geometry dataType format. When I checked online, it is kind like this - 
0x110F0000104... but I don't know how to get this.

I also got to know that there is special software like Atlas from one of my colleague, using this we are getting geometry info. I also got to know that 
 there is polygon concept in achieving this. How can I extract geographical data from map or from other source in SQL Server in Geometry format? Are there any free software available in market to achieve this functionality? Provide me examples if any.

Comment: "SQL" is a language. "SQL Server" is a Microsoft database product. It's confusing to write just "Sql" when you mean "Microsoft SQL Server".

Comment: I couldn't understand if what you are trying to accomplish is to input geographic data into a table in SQL Server or if you already have a SQL Server database with geographic data and are trying to retrieve information from it.

Comment: @CarlosMSF - Once I input geographic data in SQL table and map each with unique Id column (e.g. Region/Borough Id) . I will then retrieve Area/Borough/Name using latitude and longitude but it is my next activity. I will have to put first geopraphic data in SQL table. Hope you have undestood.

Comment: I don't know the Atlas software you mention, but you can easily load your geographic data into an SQL Server database using QGIS (free and opensource)

Comment: Thanks @CarlosMSF . I will give definitely try on QGIS software. I solved my issue using free tool - Shape2SQL (https://www.sharpgis.net/page/Shape2SQL) and Google Earth.